# extractFeatures() from the NMF package in R returns empty list for microRNA data

Tags: r, feature-extraction

I am using the NMF package in R to perform non-negative matrix factorization on RNAseq/microRNAseq data.

My first attempt was with RNAseq data (FPKM data matrix) that has been logged,empty rows removed and converted to fit the non-negativity requirements. This worked beautifully. The extractFeatures() function returned a list of indices which I was then able to use to list the genes in each feature and perform functional (GO-based) analysis on. Yay!

Then, I decided that I'd try the same trick with microRNA data (again FPKM data matrix) treated exactly the same way as RNAseq data.

#### Data looks something like this

```
                   SampleA      SampleB     SampleC     SampleD     SampleE
hsa-let-7a-2-3p    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   0.8858701    0.000000
hsa-let-7a-3p      8.723701   10.169876    8.041837   8.3992046    8.109053
hsa-let-7a-5p     14.996682   12.861308   13.739875  14.0245517   13.901233
hsa-let-7b-3p      4.911069    0.000000    5.399995   5.7433124    5.553784
hsa-let-7b-5p     11.758403   10.788349   11.648344  12.0864421   11.909324
hsa-let-7c        10.480125    6.378711   11.214152  10.2060951   10.852412
```

I have run through the rank-optimisation steps and found optimal rank (here 4). Following this, I ran the nmf function like so (simplest version possible).

```
res.mir <- nmf(data,4)
```

Then, I tried to extractFeatures from this object and I get this....

```
> s<-extractFeatures(res.mir)
> s
[[1]]
<NA>
  NA

[[2]]
<NA>
  NA

[[3]]
<NA>
  NA

[[4]]
<NA>
  NA

attr(,"method")
[1] "kim"
```

The only time I have managed to get feature indices are when I use

```
s1<-extractFeatures(res.mir,method="max")
> s1
[[1]]
<NA>
  NA

[[2]]
[1] 923

[[3]]
[2] 258  20 308 561 591

[[4]]
<NA>
  NA

attr(,"method")
[1] "max"
```

But, in this case, I only get indices for some of the features not all 4. Bizarre given I can see 4 features!

#### Questions

1. Does anyone have any advice as to how to get the features out of an NMFfitX1 object ?
2. Alternatively, does anyone know why I'm being returned an empty list ?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Use another method to extract features, i.e., if you used to use "kim", try "max". An empty list implies that there is no feature being selected based on the computed scores using the pre-specified method.

Answer (score 0):

try  `extractFeatures(res.mir, 30)`, which mean top-30 features in each component. But I didn't find out why it returns NAs default.

Comment: While it gives you the top n features, they are not selected features. All NA means no feature is selected.